# How to handle hi res and low res of application's Icon.png for iPhone and iPhone4

Tags: iphone, iphone-4, application-icon

I have already provided both Icon.png (for iPhone) and Icon@2X.png (for iPhone4). 
The thing is, when I just provided Icon.png of size 144x144, the console outputs this message:

"iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (144 x 144) don't meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)"

But this renders icon in both iPhone and iPhone4 well.

I want to be able to remove this issue so I reduced the size for Icon.png to 57x57 and created Icon@2X.png with size 144x144. After this, icon for iPhone seems fine but iPhone4 uses Icon.png and the icon renders a low res image.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: isn't @2x supposed to mean double the resolution?? 57 * 2 = 114. so make the @2x image 114 x 114. that should work... i think..

Comment: I am having this same warning (on build) and error (on validation before submitting). the funny thing is that, this same project was built/binary submitted before without any problems and, above all, I have all the icons at the proper sizes included. I am removing/re-adding the icon resources, cleaning and rebuilding just in case...

Comment: Didn't work... I'm asking a new question - EDIT: forget it, it seems this has been asked a lot. I am checking the existing questions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this solution:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html#IPHONEADDITEMS

It works!

Answer (score 6):

Heres the images you need to make to support all current devices

- iTunesArtwork – Icon for iTunes AdHoc
  distribution (512×512)
- icon@2x.png – Home screen icon for
  iPhone 4 (114×114)
- icon-72.png – Home screen icon for
  iPad (72×72)
- icon-Small@2x.png –
  Settings/Spotlight icon for iPhone 4
  (58×58)
- icon.png – Home screen icon for
  iPhone 3 (57×57)
- icon-Small-50.png – Spotlight icon
  for iPad (50×50)
- icon-Small.png - Settings/Spotlight
  icon for iPhone 3 (29×29)

From my blog http://kgutteridge.co.uk/blog/2010/07/04/icon-sizes-filenames-for-ios-devices/

Comment: I already tried this, but I found the solution just a while ago... thanks for providing these information anyways.. =]

Answer (score 2):

you need double resolution image for iphone4 and the double of 57X57 is 114X114 and not 144X144.

Answer (score 0):

The icon size will be 114X114 and not 144X144. Apple provides the following documentation for this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

So there will be 2 icons:

icon.png with 57X57
icon@2x.png with 114X114